# show form field on clicking a link with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

How can I show a form field by clicking a link , i want to show the field (with jquery/javascript) on samee place of link, so that link disappears and form box appears? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey, here's a simple example:

CSS:

```
.myclassname .form{display:none;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="myclassname">
   <a href="#" class="mylink">Link</a>
   <div class="form">
      <input type="text" value="" name="myinput" id="myinput"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
   $('.myclassname .mylink').click(function(){
      $(this).hide();
      $('.myclassname .form').show();
      return false;
   });
});
```

Cheers

G.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simple code by using HTML and JavaScript.

```
<body>
<a href="#" id="mylink" onclick="myfunction();">MY</a>
<div id="myform" style="display:none">
    <form>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
 </div>
<script>
    function myfunction(){
    document.getElementById("myform").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("mylink").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

Put the link in a div-element. [On clicking](http://api.jquery.com/click/) the link, [empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) the div and [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the *form box*.